# Mysql display chinese characters

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, phpmyadmin, cjk

I have been using php + mysql (phpmyadmin) to construct websites with Chinese contents (utf-8) for a long time.

When inputting forms, and also generate output php from db, the Chinese Words display well; but when I look at the database, although sometimes they are normal chinese characters, but something they are not (become strange strings), that made me notice that, the way that mysql handle and input data is not always utf-8.

Some experts on web mentioned, mysql were used to record the input data by latin1; nevertheless, I note that the existing charset in phpmyadmin is utf-8...

Will there be any solid way to detect the encoding format of chinese characters appeared in a phpmyadmin table cell?

Also, apart from mentioning  at header of the page, will there be any method so that I can make sure the data entered to the db is utf-8 but not others?

Thank you.

Comment: check the phpmyadmin connection encoding along with the phpmyadmin display encoding. Are they set to utf-8?

Comment: If you defined charset utf8 when created the table and also you apply mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);  when connect to mysql then it should work. As for not properly displaying on some client the comment by John seems logical to me, could do the job.

Comment: Hi, let me show you the "utf-8" content entered to db, I copied these from the cell:

Comment: �ּ֯��\�U  �E�s����Ӥl�D��123���a�U

Comment: Hi john, I think in the connection file, phpadmindisplay, all are utf-8 set...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest problem that people encounter in this regard is that they don't tell MySQL that they're sending/expecting UTF-8 encoded data when connecting to the database, so MySQL thinks it's supposed to handle latin1 encoded data and converts it accordingly. Issue the command `SET NAMES utf8` after connecting to the db or use [`mysql_set_charset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php).

Comment: mysql_select_db($database_conn_impossible, $conn_impossible);

$set_charset = 'SET NAMES utf8';
mysql_query($set_charset, $conn_impossible);

Comment: Sorry, in the connection file, I have included the above, will it be the 1st way you mentioned? also, where shall I apply mysql_set_charset? Thankyou.

Comment: OK, then this solution doesn't apply. Stab in the dark... :) `mysql_set_charset` is essentially doing the same thing as `SET NAMES`.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it just because `htmlentities();` Solution is change `echo htmlentities($email_db);` to `echo htmlentities($email_db, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');`